# oracle between clause cause ORA-12015: cannot create a fast refresh materialized view from a complex query

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I successfully create a materialized view with the script:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW orderitem_mvmt
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FAST
ON DEMAND
AS
select * from order_item;
```

Trying to increase performances I change like this

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW orderitem_mvmt
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FAST
ON DEMAND
AS
select * from order_item
where to_char(last_upd,'yyyy') between to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')-3 and  to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')+3;
```

Running the script raise the error **ORA-12015: cannot create a fast refresh materialized view from a complex query**

I don't understant how It match the Fast Refresh [Restrictions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_6002.htm#SQLRF01302)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [General Restrictions on Fast Refresh](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/basicmv.htm#i1007007)

> The defining query of the materialized view is restricted as follows:
>
> - **The materialized view must not contain references to non-repeating expressions like SYSDATE and ROWNUM.**
> - The materialized view must not contain references to RAW or LONG RAW data types.
> - It cannot contain a SELECT list subquery.
> - It cannot contain analytic functions (for example, RANK) in the SELECT clause.
> - It cannot contain a MODEL clause.
> - It cannot contain a HAVING clause with a subquery.
> - It cannot contain nested queries that have ANY, ALL, or NOT EXISTS.
> - It cannot contain a [START WITH …] CONNECT BY clause.
> - It cannot contain multiple detail tables at different sites.
> - ON COMMIT materialized views cannot have remote detail tables.
> - Nested materialized views must have a join or aggregate.
> - Materialized join views and materialized aggregate views with a GROUP BY clause cannot select from an index-organized table.

Your query contains `SYSDATE` thus you cannot use it for `FAST REFRESH`